# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter fills in seconds field with zero when it should be missing

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I'm trying to create a formatter that parses a string and creates a temporal that *does not have* the seconds field, such that formatting the Temporal Accessor will fail if seconds are required.

I would expect the following code to fail on the last line, because the temporal accessor should not have a seconds field, and the second pattern requires one, but instead the output shows the seconds field is set to zero.

```
 DateTimeFormatter partialDateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-d'T'HH:mm")
                            .toFormatter();
                    
    DateTimeFormatter fullDateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-d'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                            .toFormatter();
                    
    TemporalAccessor ta = partialDateTimeFormatter.parse("2020-01-02T06:11");
    
    LOGGER.info("seconds supported: {}",ta.isSupported(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE));
    LOGGER.info("fullDateTimeFormatter: {}",fullDateTimeFormatter.format(ta));
```

Output:

```
12:44:02.561 [main] INFO MatcherTest - seconds supported: true    
12:39:44.370 [main] INFO MatcherTest - fullDateTimeFormatter: 2020-01-2T06:11:00.000
```

I see in the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html that "A LocalTime is formed if there is at least an hour-of-day available. This involves providing default values for minute, second and fraction of second." Which is odd to me given that patterns explicitly support missing components.

So I guess my question is: *How can I override / prevent that default behavior?*

Comment: I suspect you would need to write your own class that implements the `Temporal` interface with your needed behavior. [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) provides open source code for you to peruse, if you follow the terms of their license.  … (continued)

Comment: (continued) … But that may be overkill. Personally, I would just write some handlers or wrappers that make liberal use of [`truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). To detect faulty input, just compare the time value before and after truncation — if different, you received unexpected input, so throw exception.

Comment: Regarding your mention "patterns explicitly support missing components"… Yes *formatting patterns* support missing components. But the date-time classes, the `Temporal` Implementations such as `LocalTime`, do *not* support missing components. The gap is bridged by supplying default values such as zero for minutes, seconds, and fractional second.

Comment: `parse()` does resolution as your docs say and in this case resolves both date and time of day, which in turn implies seconds. Use `parseUnresolved()` instead. Then you get `seconds supported: false` and consequently `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: SecondOfMinute`. Downside is it may also accept invalid dates and times. And if you can, avoid using `TemporalAccessor` at all. What do you want this for?

Comment: @OleV.V. I need to be able to parse a varied set of strings like "01MAY2022T06:03:22" , "NOV-17-2022T06:03" an then standardize them all while *also* maintaining the missing fields. So those two strings should produce "2022-05-01T06:03:22" , "2022-11-17T06:03". The input format would be a set of possible ones, but the output format needs to be consistent, aside from the missing fields. XML has a similar type called "partialDateTime" which allows for any lesser portions of the ISO datetime to be omitted. But the java datetimeformatter precludes this because it fills in the seconds as zero.

Comment: The way I understand that XML concept it’s for conveying some rough precision, so that 06:11:00.000 would mean that you have got something like millisecond precision whereas 06:11 alone means that you don’t know what the seconds are. Something like that? I’m afraid it gets really nasty if you also need to represent how many decimals are on the seconds.